# restore a database backup to another database

Tags: sql-server, database, ssms

There is a database name "Sample"

another database is "test"

I take backup of "Sample" and tried to restore it into "test" ,but it denied me to do so in SSMS.

Is there any way?

Comment: If you want to overwrite 'test' you must do it "WITH REPLACE". If you want to merge, you cannot do it with backup but will need to use a tool or query it yourself

Answer (score 1):

Backup using scripts option.
To generate script 
right click database select tasks and then select generate script.. option.

First remove create database line from script file and don't forgot to select current database as test while running the script file.